# graphviz,pythonでdot言語のソースを入力する方法を教えて下さい。

Tags: python, dot, graphviz

①graphviz,pythonでdot言語のソースを入力する方法を教えて下さい。
AttributeErrorがでました。
②Sourceクラスの検索方法を教えて下さい。
google,grep,pychram内で検索できますか。
よろしくお願いします。

```
from graphviz import *
temp = """
digraph dot12{
1->2    
}
"""
s = Source(temp, filename="test.gv", format="png")
print(s.source)
s.view()
print('-------------------------------------------------')
p = Graph(name='parent')
p.source=temp
print(p.source)
#    p.source=temp
#AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Comment: sourceというGraphクラスの属性は不変ですので、値を変えることができないです。

Comment: https://github.com/xflr6/graphviz/blob/master/graphviz/dot.py#L98 Getterしか定義してないですね

Answer (score 2, accepted):

① 調べて見る限り、graphvizではdotのソースを入力してグラフを作る、という使い方は想定していないようなので、別のパッケージを使うほうが早そうです。

```
import pydot
temp = """
digraph dot12{
1->2
}
"""

graph = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(temp)
graph.write_jpeg('temp.jpg',  prog='dot')
```

② Pycharmだと、Sourceクラスを定義しているコードなら、ソースコード内の「Source」を右クリック→[Go to]→[Declaration]で参照することができます。
ただし、「p.source」はプロパティであり、これを定義しているのはDotクラスの中なのですが、Pycharmでこの定義をうまく見つける方法はわかりませんでした。

Answer (score 2):

[graphviz パッケージのドキュメント](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#using-raw-dot)に、生のDOTファイルからグラフオブジェクトを構成する方法が載っています。ただしこの方法だと、作ったグラフを編集することはできないので注意してください。以下、Python 3 で実装した簡単な例と実行例です。

- sample.dot

  ```dot
  graph samplegraph {
        a -- b -- c;
        b -- d;
  }
  ```
- sample.py

  ```python
  from graphviz import Source

  dotfile = open('sample.dot', 'r')
  graph = Source(dotfile.read())
  dotfile.close()

  print(graph.source)
  ```
- 実行例

  ```
  $ python sample.py 
  graph samplegraph {
        a -- b -- c;
        b -- d;
  }
  ```

その他の graphviz の機能についても、[graphviz の API リファレンス](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html)に使い方が書かれています。多くの場合、このドキュメントの中で検索すれば事足りるはずです。